# Сопоставить определенным образом значения из нескольких массивов

Tags: php, массивы

```php
Array
(
    [id] => 81822690529384
    [product] => 160
    [conversions] => 0
    [cost] => 596.9
    [network] => 60575
)
Array
(
    [id] => 783166468822836
    [product] => 158
    [conversions] => 0
    [cost] => 570.5
    [network] => 60575
)
```

Есть длинный список подобных массивов. Нужно их как-то перебрать так, чтобы в рамках одного цикла к переменной `$network` добавлялись значения `[id]` (как строка, через запятую), но только тех массивов, в которых значение `[network]` одинаковое:

`$network = '81822690529384, 81822690529384'`

Количество уникальных [network] заранее известно и задается через другой массив и вынимается через:

`foreach ($ids as $key_1 => $network).`

Пробовал разные варианты через циклы, получилось выстреливать по одному, что в целом ок но...

```php
$network = '81822690529384';
$network = '783166468822836';
```

... но смотрится как-то не очень красиво, т.к. в цикле идет вызов `curl` через функцию и там уже следующие манипуляции и получается много-много запросов таких по одному `[id]`. Может есть более красивый вариант реализации, в котором цикл прокручивается по количеству вариантов `$network`, а не массивов в ответе?

PS: изначально поля `[network]` в ответе нет, я его добавил сам в попытках что-то нашаманить, в результате время работы стало довольно ощутимым. Изначально возвращается несколько многомерных массивов **(кол-во = `$network`**) и внутри них уже массивы с `id`, `product` и тд. Если тут можно как то тоже оптимизировать, было бы круто..
Вот все манипуляции над исходном ответом:

```php
$ids = [
    3 => 60575,
    2 => 60352,
];

foreach ($ids as $key_1 => $network) {
    $stat_rows = json_decode($hub->getRowsStat($key_1), true);
   
    for ($k=0; count($stat_rows['rows']) > $k; $k++) {
        $stat_rows['rows'][$k]['network'] = $campaign_id_network;
    }
}
```

PPS: третью неделю изучаю php, других языков не знаю пока не пинайте плз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось решить самому!

1. Посчитал количество значений в $stat_rows['rows'] и внес в переменную $length;
2. Объявил массив: ids[$network] = '';
3. Сделали цикл for

```
        for ($k = 0; $length > $k; $k++) {
            $ids[$network] .= $stat_rows['rows'][$k]['id'] . ',';
        }
```

Результат:

```
$network = '81822690529384,....';
$network = '783166468822836,...';
```